# Customer Segmentation Using RFM Interpretation of Negative Scaled Variables

Tags: r, clustering, standardization

I am doing customer segmentation using RFM. Prior to proceeding with the clustering, I log transformed my Monetary variable to account for skewness.

```
df_RFM$log_monetary <- log(df_RFM$monetary)
```

After which, I did the z-standardization using scaling.

```
df_RFM2 <- scale(df_RFM2)
```

Summary statistics before scaling, after scaling, and after clustering are as attached. My question is, how do I interpret the scaled values, especially the negative ones? It doesn't make sense to say negative frequency and negative monetary retail purchases for instance.

Thanks in advance.

[image: before scaling]

[image: after scaling]

[image: cluster summaries]

Comment: RFM is a pretty blunt instrument that direct marketers should have dumped years ago. That said, it doesn't make sense to log transform a variable and then standardize the rescaled variable using z-scores. This wiki piece makes clear that the appropriate metric for the central tendency of such a variable is either the geometric mean or the median,  as well as a geometric std dev ... see *Properties* section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution

Comment: @DJohnson, noted on using another central tendency measure for the monetary variable. However, even for recency and frequency, which are both non-transformed variables, I am getting negative values after scaling. For instance a customer who purchased today would have 0 recency values, which would turn negative upon scaling. I understand scaling is a must prior to segmentation though since my variables are of different magnitudes. Is there any other workaround?

Comment: Why are the summary stats changing for frequency and recency? In other words and at a minimum, if they are "untransformed" as you claim, then the minimums and maximums should not change, correct? My best guess is that your software is transforming *all* variables without your awareness.

Comment: If $z$-standardization means what I think it does, then $z$ = (value $-$ mean) / SD and negative $z$ just means values below the mean. Whether that's what you want to use or report is a good question but some negative $z$ values are expected in practice. The only exception is that if a variable is constant, all $z$ values are 0. Note that if you take logs first, the mean of the logs is the log of the geometric mean, so taking logs can be combined with standardization. (For me, RFM is a truncation of Read The Fine Manual, but the software or tool you're using doesn't seem the issue here.)

Comment: For anyone else who didn't know:  RFM means working with Recency – How recently did the customer purchase? Frequency – How often do they purchase? Monetary Value – How much do they spend? So, that's a matter of the variables. The software here is stated to be R.

Comment: Ok so to clarify. The first picture is the untransformed original values. Second picture is z-standardization of all variables including log transformation of monetary variable. Last picture is summary statistics of each cluster group.

Comment: @Nick Cox, so since the z-scores are essentially the number of standard deviations from the mean, can I use the original values from the first picture in interpreting the cluster results in the third picture? So from the third picture, it says cluster 3 has z-scores of 128. This means it is 128 standard deviations from the mean monetary value of 2595 (from the first picture). Meaning these are the outlier spenders?

Comment: I remain puzzled at what the real question is here. As already flagged, and as is standard, negative $z$ scores just indicate values below whatever is your mean, either as originally measured or on a transformed scale. Personally, I don't find $z$-scores especially helpful in identifying outliers as (a) I would want to look directly at the data always (b) standardization doesn't affect skewness or tail weight (c) mean and SD are themselves influenced by outliers, so if I had to choose a standardization it would more likely be (value $-$ median) / IQR.

Comment: Here that's secondary, as a value 128 SDs above the mean is almost always going to be a massive outlier. But why in doubt here? More crucially, how far you should be working and thinking on a logarithmic scale depends also on your practical objectives. In some fields outliers may be suspect values to be discounted or even discarded, but here my guess is that 359086 is in no sense an illusion; it's real money in the bank for someone.